# Django login suddently error, even though the last time it's doesn't error

Tags: python, django, authentication

I don't understand what the error i got. The last time i running my code, it's working. But suddently it's error. i don't understand why. The case is i build a form for login and signup for a new user. Signup it's working so well, but when i was try to login, it's doesn't work, but when i was try to login as admin, it's working, i can login.

views.py

```
 def newCat(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewCatForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                newcat = form.save(commit=False)
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                passwd = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                newcat.save()
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=passwd)
                auth_login(request,user)
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = NewCatForm()
        return render(request, 'girl/signup.html', {'form':form})

 def login(request):
                if request.method == "POST":
                    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                        if user is not None:
                            if user.is_active:
                                auth_login(request,user)
                                return redirect('/')
                            else:
                                error = " Sorry! Username and Password didn't match, Please try again ! "
                                print(error)
                                return render(request, 'login', {"error":error})

                else:
                    form = LoginForm()
                return render(request, 'girl/login.html', {"form":form})
```

forms.py

```
class NewCatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'girl/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    {% if error %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'girl/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create a new data</h1>
    <form method='POST' class='cat-form'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <br/>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type='submit' class='tekan'>Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Which error showing ? In login method it seems that indent problem.

Comment: Oops, i'm sorry. I forgot to show the error. On login, the error not showing, bui cannot login as user but if i login as admin, i can loggin. It's weird. I got error when i was try to signup, after i click save, this should be bring me to the main menu. But i got error. "AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Comment: urls.py ? I guess you link with admin url.

Comment: urls.py ? I guess you link with admin url.

Comment: remove the auth_login and keep login(request,user)

Comment: i don't think so, this is the urls.py
'''url(r'^cat/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^cat/signup/$', views.newCat, name='regis')'''

Comment: @Exprator i still cannot login

Comment: what is stacktrace can you post it?

Comment: and do give action="" in your form or else the post wont work

Comment: @Exprator can you explain me why my code doesn't work, becouse the last time it's working so well.

Comment: what else did you changed from the last time? may be it is conflictiing

Comment: I was try to add a new menu, the menu is Delete Account. But i give a comment to my new code but still not work.